# \lettrine causes strange line breaks

Tags: context, context-mkiv, lettrine

Since I updated to ConTeXt 2012 and mkIV, each time I want to write a dropped capital I got a strange result (I mean, that extra line break) with the first line of the paragraph the dropped capital is located. It gets worse if I use it inside a `\columnset` environment.

```
\usemodule[lettrine]
\starttext
\lettrine{A}{fter the three} \input ward
\stoptext
```

This is what I got with this minimal example:

[image: Output of the minimal example provided for Lettrine.]

Do you know how I can get rid of this? I must not update my ConTeXt installation yet...

Comment: AFAIK, the letterine module is unmaintained. Use the built-in \placeinitial macro instead.

Comment: Yeah! \placeinitial works fine. But is there any sort of documentation or something? The only thing I can't do is to put a letter before the drop capital (or the "initial"), like \lettrine did with the "Ante" option. I tried with the "before" option of \setupinitial but it returns a strange result...

Comment: @acidrums4 It’s not much, I guess, but ``\placeinitial`` has a small [section on the wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Initials). As usual, [the source](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/typo-par.mkiv#l31) has some info too.

Comment: @phg Thank you so much! I've tried all morning but I couldn't put a single '¿' character before the drop capital. I had even tried dirty hacking with `\inmargin` and friends, but when I use one of them `\placeinitial` doesn't work. I'm about to give up. However, thank you so much!

Comment: @acidrums4 I just tested and with the current version from the minimals the example code (with Lettrine) runs just fine. However, with the Context from texlive I get the same spurious space as in your image. It might be worth updating.

Comment: Well, I will update it to current version and get rid of texlive. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Aditya Could you perhaps make an answer or ...

Comment: ... @phg might want to!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works fine with the latest ConTeXt minimals (2013.08.09), which gives

[image]

An alternative is to use `\placeinitial`.

```
\setupinitial
  [location=text,
   n=2,
   color=darkred,
   distance=0em,
   hoffset=0em,
   voffset=-3ex,
   before=\blank]

\starttext
\placeinitial{A}{\sc fter the three} \input ward
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

`\placeinitial` is not as sophisticated as the `lettrine` module and does not shape the paragraph according to the shape of the letter and does not provide an easy way to place something before the initial (the `Ante=...` option in `lettrine`).